# iPhone Dev: Working with unix time?

Tags: iphone, unix

I'm actually working with fbconnect and I'm trying to get a unix time that represents a month ago. I'm really confused about this since 1970 thing. Cause some body give me a point in the right direction?

Comment: What part of 1970 is confusing to you?

Comment: Sorry, I'm basically confused on how to represent time since 1970 or calculate it, but my question has been answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), time "0" is midnight on January 1st, 1970. Every second since, another second has been added; the time right now as I write this is:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1257023557.94208
```

Most systems communicate using the Unix epoch because it is easy, de-facto standard, and allows integer arithmetic.  You can get an `NSTimeInterval` representing the duration since the epoch from an `NSDate` like this:

```
NSTimeInterval timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

An NSTimeInterval is just a double. If you want an integer -- which I imagine fbconnect needs -- just convert it (untested):

```
NSString *strtimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%u", [timestamp unsignedIntegerValue]];
```

Remember, it's just a count.  You can subtract an hour by subtracting 3600 (60 * 60), add a day by adding 86400 (24 * 60 * 60), and so forth; however, it's better in your case to start with an NSDate representing the specific time you want and allowing the library to do the arithmetic for you.

`NSDate` is probably just a wrapper around these timestamps.

Comment: Note that daylight savings, leap seconds, etc. make simply adding and subtracting seconds problematic in those edge cases. If your app doesn't depend on them, great, but if it needs to handle them properly a library that deals with them is advisable.

Comment: however, once you get beyond days when performing calendar arithmetic, things get much more complicated (different days per month, leap years, time zones, daylight savings).  Use library routines to figure out when last month is.

Comment: @ceejayoz: No, it doesn't. Unix timestamps have never accounted for them, so there are multiple times in "real time" which the same Unix timestamp represented (the last in 2006, IIRC?). Daylight savings also does not factor into Unix timestamps at all, as they are timezone agnostic (they are seconds since a time, nothing more). Therefore, the arithmetic I present works in every case for Unix timestamps.

Comment: @Jed Smith: you are right that Unix time does not take into account leap seconds or time zone shifts, but that means that if the OP wants to take such things into account, then a library is a good idea.  A month ago is usually pretty easy - as long as you can agree on what is a month ago from the 31st or 30th of March, or 29th March in a non-leap year.  And as long as you don't need a time in the range 02:00-03:00 on a Sunday when the local time switched between winter and summer (standard and daylight saving) time.  Etc.

Comment: @Jonathan: So he gets an `NSDate` for "a month ago" and calls `timeIntervalSince1970` on it...